# What is a good web development workflow for Node.js (express)?

Tags: node.js, express

Do people mostly create the front end separately from the backend and then merge the two together? Is it better just to create both at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

It's very good and best practice to seprate them. In recent years most of the advances of web development focused on this principles. Coupeling is the great concept of software archtecture. when you seprate client and server and on each of them seprate  process throug for example MVC, your application will be very loose couple. the most important benfit of sepration concern is teatabilitiy and scalability.
in my opinion and experience following paradigm is so good for modern web 
development

1. Data store : NoSQL database like MongoDB, CouchDB and for some specific project Neo4j
2. Backend : Node.js, python and in recent Scala
3. Web framework on the backend that provide a full featured REST api ( express, koa, hapi on Node) (Django on Python ) (Play on Scala)
4. Frontend: MV* framework on the client like Backbone,Angular and ember

we have used some of this technolgy and love our products.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, there is never enough time put into planning, so you don't know most of what the backend needs to provide until you start fleshing out the front end and run into limitations.

Also a lot of the endpoints tend to be combined from multiple resources, so that the frontend doesn't need to make 15 requests when it needs more information.

It's common to have a frontend team and a backend team (even if it's just one person on each), which allows you to develop both at once, without slowing down either.

The flow, in my experience, looks like this:

[image: flow]

The frontend and backend teams work on their parts, then after the UI is done and the backend team has documented the api calls, the frontend is wired to the backend (the new api calls are introduced), and the feature is complete.